# 220 AC to 220 DC Converter

Tags: power-supply, safety, ac-dc

I am designing a circuit that will give me an adjustable 220DC voltage. The load is approximately 2kohms, so the maximum current that will flow is 100mA.And I have design restrictions, it needs to be small in size. I will probably use this schematics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJIHKf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I calculated the capacitor value from|
$$V_{ripple} = \frac{I}{2fC}$$

```
I = load current (100mA)
f = AC frequency (50Hz)
Vrip=1V
```

The question is; would this circuit work? And if it is working, how can I make it more safer? I will put fuse in the 220AC input and make an insulator box for it. But I am open to recommendations. Thanks, for reading and further help.

Update:

So as suggested I asked variacs to local stores and it turns out it is very expensive and big. But one of the store managers come with the idea to use dimmer switches(similar to [this](https://c0263062.ssl.cf0.rackcdn.com/content/images/how-repair-light-switch-rotary_08704ed80d489b17b0315889a00ff2eb_3x2.jpg)) with 220-to-220 transformer(and cheap!). So new schematics looks like this;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f845pB.png)</sup>

Comment: WoW !   That 100 ohms across 220 volts is going to get really really HOT !

Comment: Do you realize that R1 will need to be **enormous** ? It will be dissipating around 1 kW !

Comment: Ah! It is the default value for schematics program, not intended to use 100 ohm, but thanks for noticing :) I will probably use a megaohm potentiometer.

Comment: But do calculate what the dissipation will be when you make it a different value and pull 100 mA out of this circuit. another comment: do not name the ground node "220DC-" this is confusing, name it "GND" or "0 V". **I do hope that this circuit is purely a theoretical excercise !** If you want to build something, stay safe and start with 12 V AC as to not get yourself killed.

Comment: Also,  whatever potentiometer you will be using. Notice that the 100 mA will go through only a small portion of the potentiometer. So you can't depend upon the wattage rating of the entire potentiometer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought about it. Do you have any recommendations for potentiometer or should I calculate the power dissipated for an infinitesimal value of potentiometer than multiply the real value with it?

Comment: Happy electrocution. Oh btw, did you know that rectified 220VAC is not 220VDC ?

Comment: If you rectify 220VAC with that circuit you will get 310VDC across the output capacitor.

Comment: A megaohm will not work either when you are aiming at 100mA load current.

Comment: You will touch that capacitor when charged to 310 V only **once** ! :-)

Comment: Why don't you lose the potentiometer and use a variac on the input?

Comment: @Steve G I know but because I can adjust the output I thought It will not make a difference at end.

Comment: @Tut I didn't use a variac before that's why :) but I will going to search for it.

Comment: As you can see by the numbers of people who commented on your question (so quickly), that your approach is not really a good one.  But your question is good.  And hopefully will guide you to a much better (and safely) solution.

Comment: @Maria, yes and I don't want to die either :) but I didn't do any kind of ac-to-dc conversion besides of using bridge rectifiers

Comment: That may be,  but look what you learned.  Educating yourself is step by step.  None of us commentors got where we are today without tripping ourselves along the way a few times.

Comment: Since your question sounds like you actually want(ed) to build this, another word of warning: Consider getting a low voltage AC supply like 24VAC and start experimenting with that. IF you really want to play with 230VAC, consider using an isolation transformer. That won't make it safe, but a little bit less dangerous.

Comment: You don't show AC GND. One of the problems with this circuit is that the DC side cannot be connected to AC GND. I don't know how mains works where you are, if one of the AC conductors is at GND potential, or if there is a separate Earth ground or what. But you would also need to consider that if you actually built this circuit.

Comment: You cannot legally attach this circuit to 220VAC from the usual source without an input transformer, so you may as well use either a step-down transformer or a variac, or both, to get you down to 220VDC.

Comment: Why do you need _smoothed_ DC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this is more of a *negative* answer to address the first update in your question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV291z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's dimmer driven variable power-supply.*

To understand why this is slightly problematic we need to look at how dimmer control works.

[image: Triac phase angle control.]

*Figure 2. Triac phase-angle control.*

C1 of Figure 1 stores the peak voltage out of the bridge rectifier. We can see from Figure 2 that the peak voltage of the AC will be the same from 0° to 90°. Only after 90° does the peak voltage start to reduce.

This may be good enough for your application.

[image]

*Figure 3. A HV linear DC supply. Source [The variable high voltage power supply 0-300V](http://www.eleccircuit.com/the-variable-high-voltage-power-supply-0-300v/). (Not reviewed by me.)*

The alternative is to use a high-voltage DC output switched-mode PSU.

**Ripple calculation**

The capacitor must supply current to the regulator for 1/2 cycle (10 ms for 50Hz).

The charge Q (coulombs) removed from the capacitor is \$Q=I \cdot t \$, where I is current and t is time.

Also \$ Q = C \cdot ΔV \$, where C is the capacitance and ΔV is the voltage drop as the current flows out.
So \$ C \cdot ΔV = Q = I \cdot t \$

Rearranging gives \$ C = \frac {I \cdot t}{ΔV} \$.

For your 0.1 A power supply, 50Hz, full-wave rectified, and a 1 V ripple specification the capacitor required is

$$ C = \frac {0.1 \cdot 0.01}{1} = 0.001 F = 1000 \mu F $$

This agrees with your calculation.

Answer (score 3):

So that the circuit being discussed can't be edited out from under this answer, here is what we are talking about:

[image]

There are so many things wrong here, it's hard to decide where to begin.

A 220 Vrms sine wave has peaks of 311 V.  Minus a couple of diode drops, let's say you will get 310 V on C1.

"25W" is a nonsensical rating for a capacitor.

Try finding a 1 mF 350 V cap, and you will see how expensive those are.

"25W" makes no sense for the diodes in this context.  This shows you really don't understand Volts, Amps, and Watts.

100 Ω for R1? Really!? Clearly you haven't even thought about doing the math.  (310 V)<sup>2</sup>/(100 Ω) = 960 W.  R1 will basically be a 1 kW space heater.  That's about the size it would need to be to not blow up.

220 VAC at 50 Hz sounds suspiciously like the power line.  If so, this circuit is quite dangerous.  The top side of R1 will be at dangerously high voltage and ground-referenced to other things in your house.  You can easily be killed by touching that node and something like a water faucet.  There are other less obvious ground points in your house, so it's nowhere near as obvious as avoiding faucets.

You show the bottom of R1 as ground, but that's just what you call it.  It might also be lethal, depending on how exactly the 220 VAC is wired, and which way around the plug is installed.  One or more diodes may even blow up if you try to connect your ground to real ground.

So how to fix this mess? Frankly, someone with so little understanding of electronics and the dangers of high voltage shouldn't even be here.  Go buy a off the shelf adjustable power supply that goes up to the voltage you want.  Let someone else that actually understands these things design it and make it at least as safe as a 200+ V output allows.

There are ways a more skilled amateur could achieve what you want, but teaching all that is required just to understand the answer is beyond the scope of this Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is flawed in that instead of using R1 as an open-loop shunt voltage regulator, you should use a series pass regulator instead, sort of like this:

[image]

None of the values of the components have been fleshed out, but the topology is there. R2 may be made active and servo the output voltage to where it needs to be without constant fiddling with the knob

Comment: I really want to downvote this answer. Among other things, about 90% of the possible settings for R2 will destroy the FET.

Comment: yes, it really needs feedback.  Something in principle like a TL431 except that 340V will let the smoke out of one of those.  You could probably use a 431 with a very careful biasing+protection network around it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: How so?  The FET is a source follower so 1:  it'd be really hard to punch through the gate oxide regardless of the value of the voltage across C1, and 2:  what window of settings of R2 would you expect to cause the demise of M1? Looking at the half-power point, with 170 volts across the transistor and 170 volts across the load yields a dissipation in each of about a watt, which doesn't seem so bad. Do you have some numbers to support your stance?

Comment: @WilliamBrodie-Tyrrell: Since it's a source follower, the feedback is there, and is intrinsic.

Comment: @What: It's a source follower, so the gate-source voltage should not get out of line.  That said, I'd probably use a NPN darlington in place of the FET.